# How to mock a record with Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to mock a record class

```java
    @Test
    public void testRecord() {
        record Rec(){}
        Mockito.mock(Rec.class);
    }
```

But it gives the error

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
    Cannot mock/spy class Rec
    Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
     - final class
        at ...
```

Which makes sense of course.

Comment: Could you provide some implementation details of the Rec class such as the access modifiers  ?

Comment: I declare it right in the test, above the mock

Answer (score 27):

### Update 15/Nov/2023

Since version 5.x, mockito switched its default mock runner to mockito-inline.

> Mockito 5 switches the default mockmaker to mockito-inline, and now requires Java 11 ([see Mockito GitHub homepage](https://Mockito%205%20switches%20the%20default%20mockmaker%20to%20mockito-inline,%20and%20now%20requires%20Java%2011))

**Use mockito 5.x**, if you cannot, follow previous answer below:

---

As the error message suggests, you cannot mock final classes with the default Mockito.

But the community came up with `mockito-inline`, an extension bringing experimental features such as mocking final classes and methods or static methods.

Just add this in your `pom.xml` and use Mockito normally.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and for Gradle:

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.11.0'
```

Comment: For any late-comers, these experimental features seem to have been upstreamed into mockito-core 5.x removing the need for that artifact.